# Weighted Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

40% of population are male, 60% are female

$$ M \sim N(0.7,0.1^2), \qquad F \sim N(0.6,0.05^2) $$

How to find the normal distribution of the whole population?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 2):

The whole population *would not* follow normal distribution, it will follow a [mixture distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution)

$$ f(x;\mu_M,\mu_F,\sigma_M^2,\sigma_F^2) = \lambda f_M(x;\mu_M,\sigma_M^2) + (1-\lambda) f_F(x;\mu_F,\sigma_F^2) $$

where $\lambda \in [0, 1]$, and $\mu_M,\mu_F$ are means and $\sigma_M^2,\sigma_F^2$ are standard deviations of normal distributions $f_M,f_F$ for males and females.

If you create simulated data as in your example and plot it you will notice that it certainly does not follow a normal distribution. You will also find that the mixture of two normal distributions perfectly fits your data.

[image: Histogram of the mixture distribution]

Comment: This looks a lot like homework to me. Be careful of providing full answers.